# Front audio jack not working on SigmaTel STAC9274D

Tags: 11.10, sound, alsa, hda-intel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Getting SigmaTel STAC9227 front audio jacks to work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19982/getting-sigmatel-stac9227-front-audio-jacks-to-work)

Firs of all, I want to say that this problem seems to be the same as the one here [Getting SigmaTel STAC9227 front audio jacks to work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/19982/getting-sigmatel-stac9227-front-audio-jacks-to-work). But seeing as it wasn't solved, I'm posting it.

I just installed Ubuntu 11.10 and am unable to output sound through the front audio jack, while the rear jack works fine. I am using the integrated audio device that comes with the Intel D975XBX2 Motherboard.

I have tried a few workarounds but without success.

**Possible models for my codec:**

```
STAC9227/9228/9229/927x
=======================
  ref           Reference board
  ref-no-jd     Reference board without HP/Mic jack detection
  3stack        D965 3stack
  5stack        D965 5stack + SPDIF
  5stack-no-fp  D965 5stack without front panel
  dell-3stack   Dell Dimension E520
  dell-bios     Fixes with Dell BIOS setup
  volknob       Fixes with volume-knob widget 0x24
  auto          BIOS setup (default)
```

I tried adding a line in the ALSA configuration file "/etc/modprobe.d/alsa-base.conf" `options snd-hda-intel model=xxxx` and tried all the models above, and it hasn't worked.

I am out of ideas. These are some relevant outputs that can help with finding the problem.

**cat /proc/asound/card0/codec#2 | grep STAC**

```
Codec: SigmaTel STAC9274D
  Device: name="STAC92xx Analog", type="Audio", device=0
  Device: name="STAC92xx Analog", type="Audio", device=0
  Device: name="STAC92xx Digital", type="SPDIF", device=1
```

**lspci -vv**

```
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 0419
    Control: I/O- Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx+
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 0, Cache Line Size: 64 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 44
    Region 0: Memory at e3200000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: <access denied>
    Kernel driver in use: HDA Intel
    Kernel modules: snd-hda-intel
```

**aplay -l**

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 0: STAC92xx Analog [STAC92xx Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: Intel [HDA Intel], device 1: STAC92xx Digital [STAC92xx Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

**Edit:**

**alsamixer**

I just tried the terminal application alsamixer. Rechecked the mute state of the headphones output with every different option in the *alsa-base.conf* file and it still isn't working.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)